# Combined Quota solution for Oracle DB 12

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

I recently came across an issue where i have 6 oracle users working on a single tablespace ( Due to some issues in their old and buggy oracle plugins i am unable to provide them with multiple tablespaces ) .

The issue is that on a 1.5 TB tablespace i need to set a combined quota of 1TB for the first 3 users , and a combined quota of 500GB for the other 3 . 
If i specify a quota of 1TB for each of the first 3 users and 500 gb for each of the next 3 obviously that will give an erroneous amount of storage in the end.
Is there a away to combine the quotas somehow ?

Note: There is no knowledge of what percentage each of the users consumes out of that 1TB so i cannot asign a quota statically for each user.

Comment: FYI - please **edit your question** to improve it, add clarifications or other details. Comments are for, er , comments.

Comment: I believe Oracle does not really have a merging or or better said a groupwise quota system out off the box.. iám pretty sure you can simulate it by making your own quota table with the needed groups and use `DBA_TS_QUOTAS` view and `alter user <user_name> quota <size> on <tablespace_name>;` in a function/stored procedure or maybe even a trigger when you need to recalculate and change the quota's`.. The trigger might be the best option because you can terminate the executen and signal the user with SIGNAL keyword besides you trigger is more automated